# Send email to and then redirect in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a website with a form in it. The form takes name, phone, email, company and a message.

I want it so that when the user clicks submit, an email is send to a predefined email account and that the user then is send to a new page.

The code that I have so far is this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:test@test.com">
```

This however just opens up the email provider prompt. This wouldn't be that bad, but I can't redirect the user after wards then.

Is there a way to do this with just javascript, or would it be easier to just use PHP?

Comment: You can't send emails using JS - you need a server for that. So go ahead with PHP, it's not hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this solely on client side javascript. You need to use a server language, such as PHP, to get the posted data and send it by email. You then have a choice, to redirect also on the server side or doing it client side.

Here's what your PHP code would look like (note I didn't test it):

```
// email the posted data
mail('your-address@mail.com', 'New message from site',
   'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] .
   'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] .
   'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] .
   'Company: ' . $_POST['company'] .
   'Message: ' . $_POST['message']);

// redirect the visitor
header('redirect-url-here');
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to do it in PHP, was just wondering if I could do it in js. Thanks!